# Twitter api stream passes tweets not as tweet object but as String

Tags: python, twitter

```
class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data.text)
```

That's an example of what i want my listener to do. I just want to print the text of the tweet that is passed but when trying to do that i get following error:

```
  File "test 2.0.py", line 72, in on_data
    print(data.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Apperently my tweets are being passed as a string rather then a tweet object. I can still print the whole data and it will give it out like it's supposed to (like a object) but in reality it's just a String that looks like a object

```html
{"created_at":"Thu Apr 18 11:44:42 +0000 2019","id":1118842788160921600,"id_str":"1118842788160921600","text":"RT @LCARS_24: Donald Trump's great fantasy\nThat he dreams of anxiously: \n\"Drain the U.S. Treasury!\" \nInstead he's facing bankruptcy.\nDonald\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1030908792597360640,"id_str":"1030908792597360640","name":"Muffy Bevin","screen_name":"MuffyBevin","location":"Massachusetts, USA","url":null,"description":"I wish we had an American President who loves the USA.  Orange is the new blech!\ud83d\udc31 #TheResistance. Invoke the 25th for the 45th.\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":739,"friends_count":742,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":24042,"statuses_count":25625,"created_at":"Sat Aug 18 20:06:24 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"981CEB","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1030913540708814849\/QVRTrBUj_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1030913540708814849\/QVRTrBUj_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1030908792597360640\/1538050843","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu Apr 18 11:31:27 +0000 2019","id":1118839453798129665,"id_str":"1118839453798129665","text":"Donald Trump's great fantasy\nThat he dreams of anxiously: \n\"Drain the U.S. Treasury!\" \nInstead he's facing bankrupt\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/l2O1k49QUZ","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":1118837452196573184,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"1118837452196573184","in_reply_to_user_id":829977013888782338,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"829977013888782338","in_reply_to_screen_name":"LCARS_24","user":{"id":829977013888782338,"id_str":"829977013888782338","name":"Bill Morris  \ud83c\udf0e","screen_name":"LCARS_24","location":null,"url":null,"description":"#TheResistance #resist #FBR #GetMoneyOut #GreenNewDeal #MedicareForAll #unhackthevote #LockTrumpUp #ImpeachTrump #impeach45 #VoteBlue #BlueWave2020","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":42828,"friends_count":47034,"listed_count":61,"favourites_count":28680,"statuses_count":65692,"created_at":"Fri Feb 10 08:55:15 +0000 2017","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/833910755560808448\/kv8iyfQh_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/833910755560808448\/kv8iyfQh_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/829977013888782338\/1512210973","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Donald Trump's great fantasy\nThat he dreams of anxiously: \n\"Drain the U.S. Treasury!\" \nInstead he's facing bankruptcy.\nDonald Trump promotes division,\nFills the air with hateful friction.\nTo be President for Life's his life's ambition.\nInstead let's make it \"life in prison.\"","display_text_range":[0,275],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":7,"favorite_count":11,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/l2O1k49QUZ","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1118839453798129665","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"LCARS_24","name":"Bill Morris  \ud83c\udf0e","id":829977013888782338,"id_str":"829977013888782338","indices":[3,12]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1555587882448"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a json object, so try:

```py
import json

class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_data(self, data):
        deserialized = json.loads(data)
        print(deserialized['text'])
```

Comment: Thanks, works now ;)
Just started a few days ago with python so fairly new to all of this :D